# Docker Nginx reverse proxy to separate container

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm having trouble creating a reverse proxy and having it point at apps that are in other containers.

What I have now is a docker-compose for Nginx, and then I want to have separate docker-containers for several different apps and have Nginx direct traffic to those apps.

My Nginx docker-compose is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
       - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My default.conf is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.mydomain.com;
  location /confluence {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.50:8090/confluence;
  }
}
```

I can access confluence directly at: *http://192.168.1.50:8090/confluence*

My compose for confluence is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: pg_confluence
    env_file:
      - env.list
    ports:
      - "5434:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pg_conf.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pg_conf.sql
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  confluence:
    image: my_custom_image/confluence:6.11.0
    container_name: confluence
    volumes:
      - confluencedata:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence
      - ./server.xml:/opt/atlassian/confluence/conf/server.xml
    environment:
      - JVM_MAXIMUM_MEMORY=2g
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  confluencedata:
  dbdata:
```

I am able to see the Nginx "Welcome" screen when I hit mydomain.com but if I hit mydomain.com/confluence it gives a not found.

So it looks like Nginx is running, just not sending the traffic to the other container properly.

**========================**

**=== Update With Solution ===**

**========================**

I ended up switching to Traefik instead of Nginx.  When I take the next step and start learning k8s this will help as well.

Although these network settings are what you need even if you stick with Nginx, I just didn't test them against Nginx, so hopefully they are helpful no matter which one you end up using.

For the confluence docker-compose.yml I added:

```
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
services: 
  confluence: 
    ... 
    networks:
      - internal
      - proxy
  db: 
    ...
    networks: 
      - internal
```

And for the traefik docker-compose.yml I added:

```
networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    networks:
      - proxy
```

I had to create the network manually with:

```
docker network create proxy
```

Comment: I suspect you got the downvote for one of two reasons: 1) what you're doing is OK for testing, but not a good practice for production (I'd suggest Kubernetes), and 2) you didn't actually explain what you're seeing in your question above (i.e., what is the current behavior? What are you expecting?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really how to use docker the correct way.

If you are in a production environment, use a real orchestration tools (nowaday `Kubernetes` is the way to go)

If you are on you computer, you can reference a name of a container (or an alias) only if you use the same network AND this network is not the default one.

A way is to have only one docker-compose file.

Another way is to use the same network across your docker-compose.

- Create a network `docker network create --driver bridge my_network`
- use it on each docker-compose you have:

  `networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my_network`

Comment: I ended up switching to use Traefik instead of Nginx, but the networks entry was the answer.  Thank you.